# Arrays inside structures

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

So I created a struct whose only element is a pointer to an array.  When I initialize this array, I get a segmentation fault.  Can you tell me why?

Here is the code:

```
typedef struct {
    int *data;
} A;

/* Class definition */
class C {
    A* a;
public:
    C(void);
};

/* Constructor */
C::C(void) {
    a->data = new int[10];
}

int main(void) {
    C();
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because class `C` holds a pointer to an `A`, which has not been initialized. So there is no `a->data` to initialize at that stage.

As an aside, your struct `A` doesn't hold a "pointer to an array", it holds a pointer to an `int`. It doesn't necessarily have to be initialized to point to a dynamically allocated array:

```
int n = 42;
A a;
a.data = &n;
```

Also, your declaration of `A` is somewhat unusual in C++, and inconsistent with that of `class C`. Usually this form is used:

```
struct A {
  int* data;
};
```